# CryptographyClient Decrypt throws 'Key does not exist' exception

Tags: c#, .net-5, azure-keyvault

I'm trying [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.keys-readme-pre#encrypt-and-decrypt) example to encrypt/decrypt a text using Azure Key Vault SDK.

I created key manually via Azure Portal. Encryption part succeeds, but decrypt throws 'Key does not exist' exception. I can't understand why, because key exists, it has *decrypt* as a permitted operation and I can confirm that in VS in a debug mode (KeyVaultKey -> KeyOperations lists 'Decrypt').

This is the full code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var keyVaultKeyIdentifier = new KeyVaultKeyIdentifier(new Uri("key-url"));
    
        var keyClient = new KeyClient(keyVaultKeyIdentifier.VaultUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    
        var keyVaultKey = keyClient.GetKey(keyVaultKeyIdentifier.Name).Value;
    
        var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(keyVaultKey.Key);
    
        byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A single block of plaintext");
    
        // encrypt the data using the algorithm RSAOAEP
        EncryptResult encryptResult = cryptoClient.Encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, plaintext);
    
        // decrypt the encrypted data. 
        // **Exception is thrown on this line**
        DecryptResult decryptResult = cryptoClient.Decrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, encryptResult.Ciphertext);
    }
```

For the reference the stack trace of an exception:

```
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(SafeNCryptKeyHandle key, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void* paddingInfo, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.Decrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.RsaCryptographyProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.RsaCryptographyProvider.Decrypt(DecryptParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.CryptographyClient.Decrypt(DecryptParameters decryptParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.CryptographyClient.Decrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm algorithm, Byte[] ciphertext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at DotNetFiveCrypto.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mike\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\DotNetFiveCrypto\Program.cs:line 32
```

I'm using .NET 5 on Windows 10, referenced SDK packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys" Version="4.2.0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are instantiating `CryptographyClient` using the public part of your key - so the SDK creates a local client, which is only capable of encrypting.

Since the private part is never exposed by Key Vault, you need to instantiate `CryptographyClient` using the Id of your key instead, so that it creates a remote client that delegates both encryption and decryption to [Key Vault REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/decrypt/decrypt).

Here's the fix:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var keyVaultKeyIdentifier = new KeyVaultKeyIdentifier(new Uri("key-url"));

    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    var keyClient = new KeyClient(keyVaultKeyIdentifier.VaultUri, credential);

    var keyVaultKey = keyClient.GetKey(keyVaultKeyIdentifier.Name).Value;

    var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(keyVaultKey.Id, credential);

    byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A single block of plaintext");

    EncryptResult encryptResult = cryptoClient.Encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, plaintext);

    DecryptResult decryptResult = cryptoClient.Decrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, encryptResult.Ciphertext);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/f6d49e3727d88f8af116a850e1f8a159a428bb10/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys/samples/Sample4_EncryptDecrypt.md)'s an additional encryption/decryption sample and [here the source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/f6d49e3727d88f8af116a850e1f8a159a428bb10/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys/src/Cryptography/CryptographyClient.cs#L83-L111) where it switches between local and remote clients.

I don't know the use case in question, but you could build a local crypto client for encryption (faster) and use the remote one for decryption (slower).